# PHP 5.3 support for strange '${}' code?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I've just upgraded to PHP 5.3 and started supporting an old website for a new client. It seems to use rather odd PHP code which I've not come across before.

Whilst trying to access $_GET or $_REQUEST variables, the developer has used the following: **${"variable_name"}**

I get notices generated due to undefined variables (presumably because PHP is not parsing the **${"variable_name"}** style code).

Changing this to **$_REQUEST['variable_name']** works as expected, but I can't go through all their code and change it as the site is massive and uses proprietry layout methods.

Does anyone know if it's possible to switch on support for these tags / codeblocks? I've taken a look in PHP.ini and there is a mention of ASP style tags and short tags but enabling these has no effect (they look totally different anyway, I just thought it was worth a shot).

Comment: Could you post a code sample?

Comment: asp style tags would be <% %>. And short tags would be <? ?> instead of <?php ?>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there is anything new with that syntax :

```
$a = 10;
var_dump(${"a"});
```

Works just fine ;-)

You problem is probably due to the fact that, before, [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) was enabled *(by default, if PHP <= 4.something)*, and is now disabled -- and that is good for security !

With register_globals set to On, any variable in `$_REQUEST` is automatically injected as a vartiable in your application *-- well, actually, this depends on the [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) configuration option, but this one almost always includes Get, Post, and Cookie, at least.*

For instance, if there is a variable like `$_GET['my_var']`, you will also have a `$my_var` variable... And this one can also be accessed with the syntax `${'my_var'}`

Considering `register_globals` is `Off` by default since something like PHP 4.2, and should disappear in PHP 6 *(if I remember correctly)*, I would advise against re-activating it... at least, if you have the time required to correct / test the code...

Comment: Thank you, I've not come across that way of doing things before! Seemed strange to me at first, but then there seems to be many ways of doing one thing in PHP

Comment: There are LOTS (too many, some would say ^^ ) of ways of doing one thing ^^

Answer (score 5):

Curly brace syntax for variables is an embedded part of PHP, and has been around for quite awhile.  The reason it exists is to resolve ambiguities with arrays and object syntaxes when using [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

From the manual:

> In order to use variable variables
>   with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you
>   write $$a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) then the parser needs to
>   know if you meant to use $a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as a
>   variable, or if you wanted $$a as the
>   variable and then the [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) index from
>   that variable. The syntax for
>   resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)}
>   for the first case and ${$a}[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for
>   the second.

It's a very handy syntax in several situations, such as using array or object variables while outputting something using [heredoc syntax](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

I won't reiterate the advice by others about using `register_globals`, I just wanted to expound on this unusual syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The ${"variable_name"} syntax is practically the same as $variable_name, except that the contents of the curly braces are evaluated first. It is supported by all recent versions of PHP, even the beta versions. What is not supported by recent versions of PHP though is the support of registering $_REQUEST (and other) variables as global variables. There's a setting for enabling it:

`register_globals = on`

It is NOT recommended for production use because of security issues though. It may be easier to run you source through some 'sed'-like tool and replace the usages with regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

The old server probably has `REGISTER_GLOBALS` on. So the weird brackets aren't the problem.

`REGISTER_GLOBALS` puts all the variables in `$_REQUEST` as regular variables in the global scope, meaning you can access `$_REQUEST['test']` can be accessed like `$test` or `${"test"}`

The bracket syntax is on by default, and I don't believe you can turn it on/off.

Answer (score 2):

`register_globals` was likely switched on. `{$variable_name}` syntax is always on, but `register_globals` turns things like `$_REQUEST['variable_name']` into `$variable_name`.

Avoid switching it on if at all possible, though - there's a reason it's been long advised against, and it's going away entirely in PHP6.

Answer (score 0):

`register_globals` is deprecated as of php 5.3 and will be removed as of php 6.0. What you want to do is use the Refactoring feature found in most PHP IDE's (zendo studio 6+) to rename the variable to something more appropriate, ie `$_GET['variable_name']`.